# How can I only use Latin subset with Google Fonts WOFF2 files?

Tags: webfonts, google-font-api, woff

I wanted to add a font with Google Fonts, and I have noticed an odd behavior.

I want to add a font with only the latin subset, I do not want latin-ext, cyrillic or cyrillic-ext subset, in order to lighten the code. I understand that's the default behavior, so I've done like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Philosopher">
```

In Firefox (and the other browsers that do not support WOFF2), I get a correct output:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Philosopher';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Philosopher'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/philosopher/v7/OttjxgcoEsufOGSINYBGLbrIa-7acMAeDBVuclsi6Gc.woff) format('woff');
}
```

But in Chrome, I get this:

```
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Philosopher';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Philosopher'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/philosopher/v7/OttjxgcoEsufOGSINYBGLV4sYYdJg5dU2qzJEVSuta0.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Philosopher';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Philosopher'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/philosopher/v7/OttjxgcoEsufOGSINYBGLZQV2lvL5Ba9FjAYK6Lx0Qk.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

I thought, maybe the latin subset is not a default behavior anymore, so I added to my `<link>` the `subset` GET parameter:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Philosopher&subset=latin">
```

But it didn't change the output. When I go with a `&subset=cyrillic`, it changes in Firefox, but the Chrome output is the same.

Is there a way to output only the latin subset?

Or is just that the WOFF2 and unicode-range won't be downloaded if there is no need on the page? And in this last case, the gain from stripping the cyrillic call is just 8 lines of code ine the css file, that to say ~300 bytes, and it just doesn't worth anything?

Comment: I would suggest not relying on google fonts as a host, but ftr you can request the latin character set with the "text" parameter: http://codepen.io/iautomation/pen/gbPwxe (see the stylesheet resource by clicking the gear icon)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The trick lies with this optimization:

```
unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
```

With this, the browser knows whether it needs to download the font, depending on the characters it just loaded in the html. <del>Chrome is currently the only one with [full support for this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-unicode-range).</del>

<del>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range) lists Firefox 36+ as completely ignoring this spec, therefore Google Fonts has to serve it a minimal font-face specification. The same happens with Safari.</del>

**EDIT: In Nov 2022 [browser support is over 98%](https://caniuse.com/?search=unicode-range).**

Anyway, that was an interesting 30 minute journey on the internet which I hope helps any further internet travellers. This should lend weight towards why you could use Google Fonts as a CDN for hosting fonts for optimal performance as opposed to serving it yourself.

Comment: from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started?hl=en#Subsets): `Please note that if a client browser supports unicode-range (http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-unicode-range) the subset parameter is ignored;`

Comment: Great answer but has some outdated info: Current Firefox and Safari now support unicode-range. http://caniuse.com/#search=unicode-range

Answer (score 3):

If you need to download font with specific set of characters from google fonts use [text parameter in google font api](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2#optimizing_your_font_requests)

example:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yomogi&text=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.-