# Google Fonts: Language selection not working

Tags: fonts, webfonts, google-font-api

I am using the Google Font [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) on quite a few client websites.

When you are customising the font on Google Fonts you have many language options to pick from:

- Greek (Supported by Roboto)
- Latin Extended (Supported by Roboto)
- Cyrillic (Supported by Roboto)
- Vietnamese (Supported by Roboto)
- Cyrillic Extended (Supported by Roboto)
- Greek Extended (Supported by Roboto)
- Latin (Supported by all Fonts)

For these client sites, I only need to use the Latin language, and don't need to load in any other languages.

However, when I load this font in and the Latin language defined, you can see all the other languages are also loaded in the generated stylesheet:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300&subset=latin

```
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/0eC6fl06luXEYWpBSJvXCBJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Fl4y0QdOxyyTHEGMXX8kcRJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/-L14Jk06m6pUHB-5mXQQnRJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/I3S1wsgSg9YCurV6PUkTORJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/NYDWBdD4gIq26G5XYbHsFBJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Pru33qjShpZSmG3z6VYwnRJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfVtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

It was my understanding that defining `&subset=latin` loads in only that language, so why are all the languages being loaded in here?

Answer (score 3):

I am copying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31455499/883303) by [Daryl Teo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850138/daryl-teo) as he seems to provide the correct answer to your question.

> The trick lies with this optimization:
>
> `unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;`
>
> With this, the browser knows whether it needs to download the font, depending on the characters it just loaded in the html.

See here which browsers have [full support for this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-unicode-range).

Earlier browsers, e.g., Firefox < 44 and Safari < 10, ignored (parts) of the spec, or it needed to be enabled, therefore Google Fonts has to serve it a minimal font-face specification.