# Google Fonts loads all types

Tags: google-font-api

If I load simple Roboto font with 300 weight, Google loads so many font in it, please have a look at this

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300
```

It loads all:

```
 cyrillic-ext, cyrillic, greek-ext, greek etc..
```

Is this normal behavior ? how can I avoid this as if I load 3 fonts, it will be loading 18 and this is serious speed issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I only use Latin subset with Google Fonts WOFF2 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720165/how-can-i-only-use-latin-subset-with-google-fonts-woff2-files)

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/113#issuecomment-353397036), actually, it only loads it all when you visit that page with a browser. If you curl that address changing the parameter you'll see the difference.